# Python dictionary sorting weird behaviour

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort a python dictionary by multiple criteria depending on a condition on its values, like:

```
d = {'27': 'good morning', '14': 'morning', '23': 'good afternoon', '25': 'amazing'}

priority_1 = 'good'
priority_2 = 'morning'
priority_3 = 'afternoon'
new_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda c: [(priority_1 and priority_2) in c[1], priority_3 in c[1]])
```

this gives:

```
[('25', 'amazing'),
 ('23', 'good afternoon'),
 ('27', 'good morning'),
 ('14', 'morning')]
```

While I expected it to return:

```
    [('25', 'amazing'),
     ('23', 'good afternoon'),
     ('14', 'morning'),
     ('27', 'good morning')]
```

More interestingly, I thought that writing `priority_1 and priority_2 in c[1]` is no different from `priority_2 and priority_1 in c[1]`, but It turns out I am mistaken, as when I change the order to `priority_2 and priority_1 in c[1]` I get a different result.

I could not find an answer in the docs regarding the effect of the order of operands when used with logical operators.

Comment: try this: `(priority_1 in c[1]) and (priority_2 in c[1])`

Comment: I do not understand your expected result

Comment: You are using logical and on strings : it's not doing what you think it's doing. Research that.

Comment: Why amazing should be sorted out first, it's not in any of the priority

Comment: @anom907zat: `True` sorts after `False`, so items where both conditions are false go in front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(priority_1 and priority_2) in c[1]` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't check if both exist in `c[1]`; it first does `(priority_1 and priority_2)` as its own expression. Doing `and` on two strings will return an empty string if either of them is empty, or the second of the two otherwise. So it always evaluates to `morning`. Then it checks if `morning` exists in `c[1]`.

Comment: `priority_1 and priority_2` evaluates to `'morning'`, not `True`.

Comment: Yes of course, you’re right. Updating the answer.